# WPF MVVM dilemma - Where to put the command that acts on collection item?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

Let's say I have the `MasterViewModel` that contain a collection of `ItemModel`. If I'd like to add new `ItemModel` to my collection, I'd put the `AddItemCommand` in that `MasterViewModel`. Now, if I'd like to display a Delete button next to each item, where would I put this command? Surely not in the `ItemModel`?!

Would I need to create almost identical copy of `ItemModel`, for example `ItemViewModel`? That would sound like a lot of prop-ing work, but even then I'm not sure how the command would be able to remove `ItemModel` from the collection.

Most obvious approach seems to be `AddItemCommand` and `RemoveItemCommand` in the `MasterViewModel`, but how to do data binding in this case? Control's DataContext is switched to a collection so I no longer have visibility of that commands from individual item level. I saw a binding trick that finds the ancestor's DataContext but that looks so hacky or not intuitive to say at least. Is this the preferred solution or there is a better approach?

Comment: ViewModel is for commands and other binding work between View and Model... Model is the business logic. So yes, you do need a ItemViewModel as well

Comment: Both commands should be implemented in the view model that hosts the collection the commands should operate on. You should not set the collection as the DataContext. The view model should be the DataContext. You simply bind to the collection/property of this view model by adjusting the `Binding.Path`. If you need help to fix your DataContext you should post your current related code. Regarding the delete command: it really depends on what data view you are using. `DataGrid` already exposes a delete command, which would save you some work.

Comment: Usually you have to bind the `SelectedItem` to the view model. When clicking an item or a control like a delete button inside this item, you automatically select the item. The delete command simply has to remove the `SelectedItem` from the source collection. You really should post related code.

Comment: thank you @BionicCode. My preference would be to use ```CommandParameter="{Binding}"``` instead of SelectedItem property

Comment: Using SelectedItem is wrong, as you would want to be able to delete any item without having to select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddItemCommand` definitely belongs in `MasterViewModel` as it can't be an operation on an individual item.

`RemoveItemCommand` also belongs in `MasterViewModel` as it will update the list of items. However, the binding doesn't follow the basic methodology.

1. Assuming the the button that triggers the command is part of the item template, then you have to use relative binding to locate the command (is this what you referred to as 'hacky' ?)

`Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveItemCommand}"`

2. You have to tell the command which item is to be deleted

`CommandParameter="{Binding}"`

and make use of this parameter in the method corresponding to your command.

Comment: I was writing the same thing. Point deserved.

Comment: Yes, that's the binding I was referring to. Probably I should say non-intuitive, not hacky, but I'll take that this is the proper way of doing this then. Thank you.